# Time series (decompose )

Tags: time-series

I'm trying to understand how the decompose function in R works for a multiplicative time series. I know how to deal with in r, I just don't understand what R does to the series to make it additive i.e how does it transform the data mathematical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading this chapter: https://otexts.com/fpp2/decomposition.html

Basically when you are working with time series, you can have the moving average trending up or down. You also have a component of seasonality/periodicity where events re-occur at certain frequencies (monthly, weekly, etc...) and then you have a random component where randomly pop out (white noise) like random selection from a bag. The mathematics behind decompose tries to find all of these components one by one. trend is like regression, white noise like Gaussian random and the seasonality is like simple pendulum in physics.